# Modified date timestamp setting default value as null instead of set timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-data-jpa

Below is the MYSQL code for table creation

```
CREATE TABLE COMPONENTS
id_components int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
date_created timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
date_modified timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

`date_created` is updated with its right value on row creation. However `date_modified` stays `NULL` at the time of creation but is updated to the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` value on update of other fields of the row.

The expected behaviour for `date_modified` is to have `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as its default value and update its value every time other column values changes

I'm inserting data from spring data JPA using the `saveAll` method without providing values for `date_created` and `date_modified`

Comment: show us the data you are inserting and updating, otherwise , its working on insert for me *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=71ecde3a1618b339e448297870ffc23f)*

Comment: You have not explain what is the problem you are facing

Comment: @RuiCosta The problem is that date_modified is getting set as null instead of default timestamp

Comment: All your columns are auto generated, what data are you inserting ? and how?